# Table state in modal doesn't update upon executing delete [React]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

A. Parent component which is responsible for rendering table within the modal.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import Modal from '@mui/material/Modal';
import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper';
import FileReceiptsTable from "./FileReceiptsTable"; 


export default function FileViewDeletePopUp({data: fileViewDeleteObj}) {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [fileReceipts, setFileReceipts] = useState([]); 
  const [isReceiptsLoaded, setIsReceiptsLoaded] = useState(false); 
  
  const domainId = fileViewDeleteObj.split("|")[0];
  const type = fileViewDeleteObj.split("|")[1];  


  function deleteFileReceiptId(fileReceiptId){
    setFileReceipts(fileReceipts.filter(fileReceipt => fileReceipt.receiptId !== fileReceiptId)); 
  }

  const passObject = {
    toDeleteFileReceipt: deleteFileReceiptId, 
    data : fileReceipts
  }; 

  useEffect(() => { 
    
    if(type == "TRANSACTION"){
        getTransactionReceiptsDetails(domainId);
    }else if(type === "EXPENSE"){
      //TODO: Get expense receipt details. 
    }
  }, []); 
    

  function handleOpen (){
      setOpen(true);    
  }

  function handleClose(){
      setOpen(false);
  }

  function getTransactionReceiptsDetails(transactionId){
      const TRANSACTION_RECEIPTS_URL = 'http://localhost:8080/transactionOps/transactionReceipts?transactionId=' + transactionId; 

      fetch(TRANSACTION_RECEIPTS_URL)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
       
        setIsReceiptsLoaded(true); 
        setFileReceipts(data); 
      }); 
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Button onClick={handleOpen}>Open modal</Button>
      <Modal
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>

        <Box>
          <Paper >
            { isReceiptsLoaded && <FileReceiptsTable data={passObject}/> }
          </Paper>
        </Box>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}
```

B. Child component which renders the table.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { useTable } from 'react-table';
import Table from '@mui/material/Table';
import TableBody from '@mui/material/TableBody';
import TableCell from '@mui/material/TableCell';
import TableContainer from '@mui/material/TableContainer';
import TableHead from '@mui/material/TableHead';
import TableRow from '@mui/material/TableRow';
import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper';
import TableFooter from '@mui/material/TableFooter';
import TablePagination from '@mui/material/TablePagination';
import FileViewDeleteOperation from './FileViewDeleteOperations';

export default function FileReceiptsTable({ data: passObject }) {


  const columns = React.useMemo(

    () => [
      {
        Header: 'File Receipt',
        accessor: 'receiptId',
      },
      {
        Header: 'Domain ID',
        accessor: 'domainId'
      },
      {
        Header: 'File Operations',
        Cell: ({ row }) => {
          const data = row.original;
          
          const passObjectLevel2 = {
            onDeleteReceipt : passObject.toDeleteFileReceipt, 
            dataId : data
          }

          return (
            <FileViewDeleteOperation data={passObjectLevel2}></FileViewDeleteOperation>
          )
        }
      }
    ],
    []
  )

  const tableInstance = useTable({ columns, data: passObject.data, initialState: { pageIndex: 2 } })
  const {
    headerGroups,
    rows,
    prepareRow,

  } = tableInstance


  const [page, setPage] = React.useState(0);
  const [rowsPerPage, setRowsPerPage] = React.useState(5);
  const emptyRows = rowsPerPage - Math.min(rowsPerPage, rows.length - page * rowsPerPage);

  function handleChangeRowsPerPage(event) {
    setRowsPerPage(parseInt(event.target.value, 5));
    setPage(0);
  }

  function handleChangePage(event, newPage) {
    setPage(newPage);
  }

  return (
    <TableContainer component={Paper}>
      <Table sx={{ minWidth: 650 }} aria-label="simple table">
        <TableHead>
          {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (

            <TableRow {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
              { headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
                <TableCell align="center" {...column.getHeaderProps()}>{
                  column.render('Header')}
                </TableCell>
              ))}
            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableHead>

        <TableBody>
          {rows
            .slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage)
            .map((row, index) => {
              prepareRow(row)

              return (
                <TableRow key={index}>
                  { row.cells.map((cell, index) => {
                    if (index == 6) {
                      // Reduce the width of purpose. 
                      return (

                        <TableCell sx={{ maxWidth: 135 }} {...cell.getCellProps()}>{
                          cell.render('Cell')
                        }
                        </TableCell>
                      )
                    } else {
                      return (
                        <TableCell  {...cell.getCellProps()}> {
                          cell.render('Cell')}
                        </TableCell>
                      )
                    }
                  }
                  )}
                </TableRow>
              )
            })}
          {emptyRows > 0 && (
            <TableRow style={{ height: 53 * emptyRows }}>
              <TableCell colSpan={6}>
              </TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          )}
        </TableBody>

        <TableFooter>
          <TableRow>
            <TablePagination
              rowsPerPageOptions={[5]}
              count={rows.length}
              rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
              page={page}
              onPageChange={handleChangePage}
              onRowsPerPageChange={handleChangeRowsPerPage}
            />
          </TableRow>
        </TableFooter>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
  )
}
```

C. Child(Child) component which renders the operations.

```
import React from 'react';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';

export default function FileViewDeleteOperation({ data: passObject }) {

    function deleteTransactionReceipt(receiptId) {
        console.log("A -> a's child -> a's child (child) -> invoking function of delete in A"); 
        // Invoking parent function. 
        passObject.onDeleteReceipt(passObject.dataId.receiptId); 

        // Expectation is to delete the row and update the table in the modal. 
    }

    // // TODO: Change to view. 
    // function handleOnClickForView(event) {
    //     // event.preventDefault();
    //     //  navigate("/internationalTransactions/edit", { state: { transactionObj: event.target.value } });
    // }

    function handleOnClickForDelete(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        //TODO: Function to identify which domain the particular receipt belongs to. 
        deleteTransactionReceipt(event.target.value); 
    }; 

    return (
        <div>
            {/* <Button variant="contained" size = "small" onClick = {handleOnClickForView}>View</Button> */}
            &nbsp; 
            <Button variant="contained" size = "small" onClick = {handleOnClickForDelete} > Delete </Button>

         
        </div>
    ); 
}
```

Now when operation of delete is performed in C, I want the state of B updated via A. That is a record getting deleted. Problem is that doesn't happen. I believe its got something to do with the modal rendering before the state updation.

Could anyone review the same and suggest solutions.

Expectation is to make sure that the table view is updated with the new records after the deletion of a specific record achieved through a click of a delete button via FileViewDeleteOperation.

Comment: I figured out how to achieve this. 

This article was helpful. 
https://aguidehub.com/blog/2023-03-11-how-to-delete-row-of-mui-table-in-react-js/

In addition what I did was I wrapped the parent function to set the data and passed that along so both parent and child variables are in sync. Operation would be redundant but gets the job done.